# Creating one table from another using cql

Tags: cassandra, cql, nosql

Suppose i have a table of the following form in cassandra:

## Id     Event      Timestamp

111     Ongoing    1220000

111    Closed      1228888

111    Resolved    1278888

122    Closed      1346666

122    Resoved      1366666

Id and timestamp are the primary keys.

I want an output table called initial, such that it contains only the 1st event corresponding to each id..ie:

## initial

Ongoing

Closed

How can I obtain this table using **only cql** as cql does not support INSERT INTO..SELECT FROM queries.

Comment: Cassandra does not support it because there is no way to do it efficiently.

Comment: You could (theoretically) do this with triggers. Take a look here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-0-prototype-triggers-support

Comment: @mikea: But I cannot use Java, I have to do all this using cql only.

Comment: @AsthaSachdev I understand that but a trigger is a single class and that class is then embedded in the cassandra node so it isn't like a separate java application. As such, it is the only potential solution since you can't do it with cql.